# How can do video playlist in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

laravel create video upload file and how can arrange this as video playlist.

Comment: hey you.plz unhold my question .ok?I edited already.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For uploading i suggest  [DropZoneJs](https://www.dropzonejs.com/)

- After you upload videos , store them somewhere, like amazon s3
- then , store link on database
- then , use temporary link to show them for your user, base on your business model [Laravel Docs temporary link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls#signed-urls)

Comment: as udemy  learning video lessons playlist

Comment: your question is about the whole system or you want me to introduce services and technology?

Comment: I want to know how create video course lists .after upload and do playlist by html5 .right?